# Finding words in a file in which all characters are contained in another word

Tags: python, file, for-loop

so I'm doing this http://wiki.openhatch.org/Scrabble_challenge#Step_3:_find_valid_words and I've gotten stuck with one part. I'm trying to use nested loops to go through every word in the word list (a text file I have open), and for every letter in that word, see if that letter is contained in the user input. my code so far is

```
import argparse
import sys

file=open('sowpods.txt','r')#opens the file of words used in scrabble
scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
         "x": 8, "z": 10}#dictionary for letter values
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='designed to help in scrabble')
#command line interface using argparse module
parser.add_argument("word",help="input your letters",nargs='?')#adds the 
positional argument with description
args=parser.parse_args()

if args.word is None:
    print('error I need letters to work')
    sys.exit()
else:
    print(str.lower(args.word))#converts the the input for argument word 
into lowercase letters
for letter in file:
    i=str.lower(letter)
    for i in args.word:
        valid=[]
        valid.append(i)
        print(valid)
```

the expected output should look like this

```
python scrabble.by ZZAAEEI
size
ziz
```

basically a list of the valid words.

once I have this list I can get the value of the word using the scores dictionary but I'm stuck since I thought nested loops would be the best way. thanks for any help.

the file sowpods.txt contains a list of words a brief snippet it

```
AA AAH AAHED AAHING AAHS AAL AALII AALIIS AALS AARDVARK AARDVARKS AARDWOLF AARDWOLVES AARGH AARRGH AARRGHH AARTI AARTIS AAS AASVOGEL AASVOGELS AB ABA ABAC ABACA ABACAS ABACI ABACK ABACS ABACTERIAL ABACTINAL ABACTINALLY a small snippet it's pretty much a file of all valid scrabble words
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `set difference` operation:

```
word = args.word.lower()
valid = []
for line in file:
    line = line.lower().strip()
    if not (set(line) - set(word)):
        valid.append(i)

print(valid)
```

If `line` has all characters contained in `word`, then the set difference between these two will be an empty set, so `not <empty set>` is `True`.

I'm hoping each word in your file is contained on a separate line, otherwise this will neither work nor be efficient if it did.

Example:

```
⇒ word = ZZAAEEI
  line = zeze

⇒ set_word = {'z', 'a', 'e', 'i'}
  set_line = {'z', 'e' }

⇒ set_line - set_word = {'z', 'e' } - {'z', 'a', 'e', 'i'} 

⇒ set()
```

Comment: tried that it didnt work too well
   
    validword=[]
    s=list(args.word)
    for word in wordlist:
        piece=True
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in s:
                piece=False
                break
            elif piece:
                s.remove(letter)
                total=0
                for i in s:
                    total=total+scores[letter]
            validword.append([total,word])

however my output still wrong 
if i use ASADEF as my rack i get
    0 and the word is sab
    2 and the word is ea
    4 and the word is aa